# Submit + Modal box : Dont trigger submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, modal-dialog, submit

I got redirection on link "/qsd.html?firstname=test" and my modal dosnt open..
I try so many thing on google, but i cant solve it ..

I just want my modal open if input dosnt blank.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal" style="display: none">
      <button class="close">X</button>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-content">I am a modal</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <form>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="fname"
        name="firstname"
        placeholder="e.g. My TikToken"
        required
      />
      <input type="submit" id="myBtn" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <script>
      var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
      var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
      var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
      var inputName = document.getElementById("fname").value;

      // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
      btn.addEvenetListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (inputName !== "") {
          modal.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          alert("Input cannot be blank.");
        }
      });

      // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
      span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      };

      // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
      window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
        }
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

you would be great if you could help me, thank you very much

Comment: The "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." message is there for a reason. Please don't just put un-related text to fill the word count criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You're listening to the button submit, but actually you want to listen to your form submit. Change this line to:

```
<form id="theForm">
```

Then see below that we'll change what we're listening to (not the button). When your button gets clicked, your code tests for `inputName` - the problem is, you set `inputName` before anything happened, so it will be blank. Instead get that value from within your button click event. Also you have a typo `addEvenetListener`

Remove this: `var inputName = document.getElementById("fname").value;`

Change your listener to be on FORM submit (not button) like so, then add your inputName check inside it:

```
var theForm = document.getElementById('theForm');
theForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputName = document.getElementById("fname").value; 
              // .....
```

Finally, you asked about checking multiple inputs on submit. Here's a way to do it using an array of elements/messages. For this example you have 5 elements with ids "element1","element2",etc. You can change these obviously

```
var theForm = document.getElementById('theForm');
theForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var elements = [ 
    ["fname", "You need to put in a value for element 1"],
    ["lname", "You need to put in a value for element 2"],
    ["supply", "You need to put in a value for element 3"],
    ["decimals", "You need to put in a value for element 4"],
    ["ownship", "You need to put in a value for element 5"]
  ];

  // now loop through them and if any of them are not filled alert the user

  var errors= []; // we'll put any error messages in here

  elements.forEach(el => {
    // el is one of the arrays inside of elements
    if (document.getElementById(el[0]) && document.getElementById(el[0]).value.trim() == "") errors.push(el[1]);
  })

  if (errors.length >0 {
    alert("There are errors: \n" + errors.join("\n");
    // if you want to stop the modal from showing, just uncomment the next line
    // return;
  }
})
```

Comment: // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
  
   btn.addEvenetListener("submit", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
      var inputName = document.getElementById("fname").value; 
        if (inputName !== "") {
          modal.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          alert("Input cannot be blank.");
        }
      });

Can't do it, keep redirecting me to index.html?

Comment: You had a typo (addEvenetListener) I fixed it in my answer just now

Comment: Hey, i'm so mad, i try and i try but not working ... I got this : 

  btn.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
      var inputName = document.getElementById("fname").value; 
   e.preventDefault();
        if (inputName !== "") {
          modal.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          alert("Input cannot be blank.");
        }
      });

Comment: My bad, I missed that you were listening to the wrong thing - you need to listen for form.submit (not button submit). answer updated

Comment: Bro, ur legend ! I lost more than one day and can't make it alone, In addition you explain, so I learn! ! Last thing, can i make it for all input ? Not only for fname but for Name, Fname, Age. I got 5 input, please. I found this one maybe  ? (getElementsById("myCircle1 myCircle2 myCircle3 myCircle4"))

Comment: are all 5 regular inputs? (not select or checkbox/radio)?

Comment: 4 Regular and only 1 type="number"

Comment: ok, updated. If this answered your questin please mark it as the answer. thx

Comment: I try to put the last lines of code inside, before and after "if" but i think i'm very newbie and i can't make it. Can u tell me where i need to put last lines ?

Comment: Back to html? redirection problem ..    ["fname", "You need to put in a value for element 1"],
    ["lname", "You need to put in a value for element 2"],
    ["supply", "You need to put in a value for element 3"],
    ["decimals", "You need to put in a value for element 4"],
    ["ownship", "You need to put in a value for element 5"] What is "You need" .. just a value ?

Comment: "you need...." is the message that gets displayed if the user leaves that input empty. What redirection problem?

Comment: When i click submit, its redirect me to index.html?fname=test ... I got this last : 
  var theForm = document.getElementById('theForm');
theForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var elements = [ 
   ["fname", "You need to put in a value for element 1"],
    ["lname", "You need to put in a value for element 2"],
    ["supply", "You need to put in a value for element 3"],
    ["decimals", "You need to put in a value for element 4"],
    ["ownship", "You need to put in a value for element 5"]
  .....

Comment: Sorry, moving too fast. Look at my answer now in the middle - the large block of code that starts with `var theForm = document.getEleme...` take that whole bit of code and use it in yours.

Comment: @clicdesuu - did this solution end up helping to solve your question? If so, please mark as the answer. Thanks